# iphone : How to copy selected song of iphone library to document directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to copy a particular selected song of iphone library into my app's Document Directory.

How can i do that?

Comment: Cannot be done. You can reference content in the music library in order to play etc but you can't programmatically take it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ankit: Here is what you can refer to:

[TSLibraryImport](https://bitbucket.org/artgillespie/tslibraryimport)

Hope this helps